# dispatching function/action vs dispatching {type: x}

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When calling

```
store.dispatch(...)
```

we can use it like so (1):

```
store.dispatch(dispatch => {
   dispatch(someOtherAction())
});
```

or we can use it like so (2):

```
store.dispatch({type: constants.X})
```

First question: What are the two different types arguments to dispatch called?
Second question: What is the difference between calling (1) versus calling (2)?

Answer (score 0):

In (1), you're dispatching a "thunk." In (2), you're dispatching an "action." Additionally, in (1), `someOtherAction` is an "action creator." You need some kind of additional middleware (e.g., `redux-thunk`) to dispatch a thunk.

Generally, your goal is to dispatch actions, but if you need to asynchronously dispatch an action (e.g., after an API call), you can use a thunk to be able to dispatch the action asynchronously. For example:

```
store.dispatch(dispatch => {
  fetch('api/user')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(user => {
      dispatch(loadUser(user))
    })
});
```

In this example, we take advantage of the thunk concept by only dispatching a user-loading action after the user has been loaded from some API.

Comment: right, but if you do `dispatch({type: x})` it goes straight to the redux reducer thing which then changes the root state and that calls mapStateToProps?